# "Cannot open database requested by the login" error

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-express

I get this error:

> Cannot open database "SQWvNetSCID" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'nAC\Scott'.

`nAC\Scott` is who I am logged in as on the computer.  However, in SQL management studio the users for the `SQWvNetSCID` db includes `dbo`.  Which under the security tab of the database in general `(localhost\sqlexpress)` has the entry of `nAC\Scott`.  It also is included under 'users mapped to this login'.

Even with all of this it still gives me the error. Maybe my connection strings will shed some light on the situation.

```
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=accumbens\sqlexpress;;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb" />
    <add name="SQWConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=TSTEST2;Initial Catalog=SQWvNetSCID;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=hybrid" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


     <add name="SmartQWebContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Entities.SmartQWeb.csdl|res://*/Models.Entities.SmartQWeb.ssdl|res://*/Models.Entities.SmartQWeb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SQWvNetSCID;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />


    </connectionStrings>
```

I should note that I have recently moved to vs2012.

I realize that this may be a duplicate, but every similar question has answers that I have either tried or already have entered properly.

Comment: I hope that isn't your real sa password...and I hope that you [don't really use sa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642673/can-i-remove-sa-login-from-sql-server).

Comment: ha!  It isn't and I don't!    But I ended up getting it to work by copying a working connection string from the server explorer...

Comment: Funny. You never know!

Answer (score 0):

The winning sql connection string was:

```
 <add name="SmartQWebContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Entities.SmartQWeb.csdl|res://*/Models.Entities.SmartQWeb.ssdl|res://*/Models.Entities.SmartQWeb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot; Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=SQWNetSCID;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Which was copied from the server explorer connection.