# If an Active Directory account is used to log in the sql server service why does sa continue to show up when running sp_who2?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a security project and would like to remove the sa account completely from our SQL Servers.  The SQL Services are all using Active Directory Accounts.  However, when looking at sp_who2 the sa account appears for:

LOG WRITER
RECOVERY WRITER 
LAZY WRITER
LOCK MONITOR
SIGNAL HANDLER
etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I remove sa login from SQL server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642673/can-i-remove-sa-login-from-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/principals-database-engine

> The sa login has all permissions on the server and cannot be limited.
>   The sa login cannot be dropped, but it can be disabled so that no one
>   can use it.

So you should disable it.

Answer (score 0):

In any system with a reasonably robust system of attributing processes to a security principal (i.e. login), *something* has to be attributed to running system processes. This is orthogonal to being able to log in using the same account. Here, you're seeing the `sa` account run things like lazy writer, deadlock monitor, etc that are critical for the system to run. But, that `sa` is running them isn't a security risk; being able to log in as that account is, though. So, if you're worried about that, do something like `alter login [sa] disable;`. Make sure you've got a similarly provisioned account before you do that though otherwise you could lock yourself out of being able to do ad hoc administrative tasks!