# Install SQL Server Express 2022 with mixed mode but NOT the sa account

Tags: sql-server

I want to install SQL Server Express 2022 via silent install (unattended).

However I want to create the instance to use mixed mode but not the `sa` account.

I saw `/SECURITYMODE=SQL` but it seems that parameter only uses the `sa` account.

Can you not use a different account (user) / password other than `sa` during a silent install?

We have used a silent install command parameters but it creates the instance as Windows authentication:

```
/x:%SystemDrive%\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU 
/Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /HIDECONSOLE=1 /UPDATEENABLED=0 
/ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL,Tools 
/SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" 
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS" "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" 
/INSTANCENAME=[SQL_INSTANCE_NAME]`
```

But I would like to install the instance as mixed mode but not using the `sa` account. During our install we ask if they want to install via Windows authentication or mixed mode, if they choose mixed mode we provide an edit box for the username and the password.

So I would like to use the username and password they have provided.

Any ideas?

Comment: Been a while, but I don't think you can drop the SA account, but you can disable it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/472207/correct-way-to-disable-login-for-sa-account

Comment: Create the user SQL account after installation with `CREATE LOGIN` with the name and password. Use `ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER YourUser` if the login needs sysadmin permissions. You can also disable the sa account, if desired.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642673/can-i-remove-sa-login-from-sql-server